# Armadillo : solving Ax=b allocates heap?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, real-time, armadillo

I'm looking for a Math library for doing **real-time** jobs and i'd like to know if the library **Armadillo** can, for example, perform x=A\b in real time **without allocating on the heap** (or is it a way, by pre allocating on the heap at startup).

i could maybe look into the code but it uses LAPACK as a library and **i don't know where to look**

Could someone help me find the code where it solves Ax=b? And see if it uses heap allocation? Another way would be to count the heap allocated before and after but **how to do that**? HeapWalk?

thanks

Jeff

Comment: Looking through some source code found on Google, it looks like Armadillo uses dynamic allocation per default, but that you can do some of the allocation compile time.

Comment: yes but how to check if a specific function uses temporary variables created on the heap?

Comment: Does it call anything that ends up with a `new`/`malloc` ? You cannot easily do these kinds of checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Perfmon.exe, i was able to check the memory size of the program just before and just after the function i suspected of allocating on the heap. And the difference was of a little bit more than 100k for a variable of 100k...